# what is magnitude responce at ω = π/2M for freqz function

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter, dsp-core, frequency-response, finite-impulse-response

what is magnitude responce at ω = π/2M.Code Given is

```
M=8 % Channel
x=512*8
d1=kaiser(N,B) 
d1=fir1(N-1,wc/pi,w); 
[h1,fre1]=freqz(d1,1,x) 
a1=max(abs(h1)); 
plot(fre1/pi,a1)
```

find magnitude at w=π/2M.

Comment: Your question [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25393/find-magnitude-responce-at-omega-dfrac-pi2m-where-m-is-the-number-of-c) was not answered ?

Comment: My answer is given at: <http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/25393/find-magnitude-responce-at-omega-dfrac-pi2m-where-m-is-the-number-of-c>